# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType on a connect 4 game

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am learning python and for training Im making a connect4 game.
As I'm trying to erase all faulty inputs from the "player" I wanted to just ask input for the "column" and it would automatically add on the last available "row", unfortunately I haven't figured out a way to make it.

Here is what i have so far:

EDIT: now with all code pasted

```py
def main():
    board = [
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
    ]

    board_list = []
    while len(board[0]) > len(board_list):
        board_list.append(str(len(board_list) + 1))

    header()

    active_player_index = 0
    players = ["Vasco", "PC"]
    symbols = ["O", "X"]
    player = players[active_player_index]

    while not find_winner(board):
        # show the board
        player = players[active_player_index]
        symbol = symbols[active_player_index]

        announce_turn(player)
        show_board(board)
        if not choose_location(board, symbol):
            print()
            print("You're an UBER IDIOT!")
            print("That spot was already used!")
            print()
            continue

        #   toggle active player
        active_player_index = (active_player_index + 1) % len(player)

    footer()


def header():
    print()
    print("-----------------------------")
    print("----------WHALECUM-----------")
    print("-----------------------------")
    print("----------CONNECT 4----------")
    print("-----------------------------")


def footer():
    print()
    print("-----------------------------")
    print("-----------THE END-----------")
    print("-----------------------------")


def show_board(board):
    print()
    for row in board:
        print("| ", end='')
        for cell in row:
            symbol = cell if cell is not None else " "
            print(symbol, end=" | ")
        print()
    for index, r in enumerate(board[0], start=1):
        print(f"  {index} ", end="")
    print()


def announce_turn(player):
    print()
    print(f"It's {player} turn!")
    print()
    print("Pick your column...")
    print()
    print("Here's the Board:")
    print()


def choose_location(board, symbol, board_list):
    column = input("Choose a column: ")
    while column not in board_list:
        print(f"{column} is not an option, try again")
        column = input("Choose a column: ")
    column = int(column) - 1
    row = None

    while board[row][column] is None:
        row += 1
    row = row - 1
    cell = board[row][column]
    if cell is not None:
        return False

    board[row][column] = symbol
    return True


def find_winner(board):
    sequences = get_winning_sequences(board)

    for cells in sequences:
        symbol1 = cells[0]
        if symbol1 and all(symbol1 == cell for cell in cells):
            return True

    return False


def get_winning_sequences(board):
    sequences = []

    # win by row
    rows = board
    sequences.extend(rows)

    # win by columns
    for col_idx in range(0, 3):
        col = [
            board[0][col_idx],
            board[1][col_idx],
            board[2][col_idx],
        ]
        sequences.append(col)

    # win by diagonals
    diagonals = [
        [board[0][0], board[1][1], board[2][2]],
        [board[0][2], board[1][1], board[2][0]],
    ]
    sequences.extend(diagonals)

    return sequences


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is this your entire program? How are you calling `choose_location`? Which line is the error message?

Comment: it's not the entire program, I see now that I should've added the entire code, the erros comes from ```while board[row][column] is None:```

Comment: You set `row` to `None`, and then do `board[row]`.  Why?

Comment: @VascoRodrigues I would suggest giving a small section of where your code fails. Giving the entire code is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, your StackOverflow questions will be better if the code you post is runnable and demonstrates the problem or situation relevant for your question. I started with your code and added this to the end of `main()` to make it do something:

```
result = choose_location(board, '0', board_list)
print(result)
for r in board:
    print(r)
```

Then I ran it and saw this error. This stacktrace would have been good to include in your question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "x.py", line 19, in main
    result = choose_location(board, '0', board_list)
  File "x.py", line 33, in choose_location
    while board[row][column] is None:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

You can fix the indexing problems by setting things up differently. Initialize row to zero, not `None`. And add a check for the max possible row index.

```
row = 0
n_rows = len(board)
while row < n_rows and board[row][column] is None:
    row += 1
```

By the way, I think you can get rid of `board_list`. It seems unnecessary. You know that the legal columns must be in `range(1, len(board[0] + 1))`.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to get lowest position for given column

```
# returns [row, col] of players piece, returns None if column is filled up
def get_row(col, board):
    if board[0][col] != None:# column is filled up
        return None
    for row in range(7):# find lowest unfilled position
        if (board[row][col] != None) or (row == 6):# place is filled or at bottom of board
            return [row-1, col]
```